# Exclude weekend from the dates passed in a query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to remove weekend from a query whose where clause has date parameters?

```
select * from table_name where startdate > '2019-01-01' and enddate < '2019-01-31'
Date             Day          Asset Price
01-01-2019      Tuesday      A        5
02-01-2019      Wednesday    B        20
03-01-2019      Thursday     C        87
04-01-2019      Friday       D        34
05-01-2019      Saturday     E        12
06-01-2019      Sunday       F       214
07-01-2019      Monday       G        32
08-01-2019      Tuesday      H        45
09-01-2019      Wednesday    I        67
```

So when the above query is ran then Asset E and F should not come in the output.

Comment: Remove weekends? Show us some sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Try this one (eg. mysql, but every major sql format will have analogical function): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp Then ```weekday(startdate)<5```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an use function DAYNAME here to avoid weekends -

```
select *
from table_name
where startdate > '2019-01-01' and enddate < '2019-01-31'
and upper(dayname(Date)) not in ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');
```

Comment: Thanks! it works . Is it possible to count the number of weekdays for a given set of dates in the where clause ?

Comment: @max092012, ask a new question instead.

Comment: @max092012, Completely agree with Jarlh as that answer would be different than your original question.

Answer (score 1):

`DAYNAME` is not ideal as it's result depends on your `CURRENT LOCALE LC_TIME` setting. `DAYOFWEEK` or `DAYOFWEEK_ISO` would be better. E.g.

```
select *
from table_name
where startdate > '2019-01-01' and enddate < '2019-01-31'
and DAYOFWEEK_ISO("Date") < 6;
```